# Check if Json field is Null or does not exist via function

Tags: node.js

I am reading the body of a post which is a json doc and comes from a Angular App.
No problems there, if the user did not enter any data into some fields the Angular app, it sends null value. I have a data class which holds the structure of the doc which in this case is a contact. So my code looks like this

```
var quickContact = new contacts.quickContact
quickContact.type ="contact"
quickContact.initials = req.body.initials
```

this will return me a

```
{ "type" : "contact", "initials" : null }
```

to avoid any null value fields i use this code

```
var quickContact = new contacts.quickContact
quickContact.type ="contact"
if (req.body.initials){
    quickContact.initials = req.body.initials
}
```

now i get the desired output of

```
{ "type" : "contact"}
```

So my question is, how can i wrap this check if null into a function which i can call easily and pass the field name to make the code a bit cleaner as i have like 50 fields i have to check.

Answer (score 0):

To generalize your `if` statement across all potential fields on `req.body`, you can introduce iteration.

The general approach would be to iterate over the key/value pairs of `req.body` and add non-falsy values to `quickContact`:

```
for (const [key,value] of Object.entries(req.body)) {
  if (req.body[key]) { // <-- only set truthy values
    quickContact[key] = req.body[key];
  }
}
```

Note: The condition above will only set truthy values. If you want to only set non-`null` values, you have to be explicit:

```
for (const [key,value] of Object.entries(req.body)) {
  if (req.body[key] !== null) { // <-- only set non-null values
    quickContact[key] = req.body[key];
  }
}
```

Comment: that would work if it would be a simple doc but in some cases the name of the doc does not match the quickContact structure like for phone numbers i actually collect all phone numbers and stick them into an array of objects.

Comment: Give an example for the phone numbers too, then. Otherwise we literally don't have the information to help you from your original post.